# Not able to populate my smart contract with data after deployment

Tags: solidity, truffle-migration

I want to populate my smart contract with data. I am using truffle framework. In migrations file for the smart contract I'm populating the data but it is giving error:

```
TypeError: instance.create is not a function
    at newFunction (/home/user/Desktop/new/migrations/2_initial_migration.js:17:14)
```

Migration File:

```
var Storage = artifacts.require("./Storage.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Storage)
    .then(() => Storage.deployed())
    .then((instance) => {
        instance.create("Allahbad", "Sanket", "car", "automobile","11-12-12", 1234);
    });
}
```

Smart Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract NPA {

    struct NPADat {
        uint id;
        string bankName;
        string borrowName;
        string asset;
        string sector;
        string date;
        int Auction_id;
    }
    NPADat [] public npa;
    uint public nextId;

   function create(string memory bankName, string memory bname, string memory asset, string memory sector,  string memory Date, int auctionId  ) public{
        npa.push(NPADat(nextId, bankName, bname, asset, sector, Date, auctionId));
        nextId++;
    }

    function readId(uint id) view public returns(uint, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, int){
        for(uint i=0; i<npa.length; i++){
            if(npa[i].id==id){
                return(npa[i].id, npa[i].bankName, npa[i].borrowName, npa[i].asset, npa[i].sector, npa[i].date, npa[i].Auction_id);
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Start with `console.log(instance)` in order to understand better what it is.

Comment: Also, since your contract name is `NPA`, change `artifacts.require("./Storage.sol")` to `artifacts.require("NPA")`.